# Unable to Detect NVIDIA RTX 4080 Laptop GPU for CUDA in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, nvidia

**Description:**

I'm attempting to utilize my NVIDIA RTX 4080 laptop GPU for training and running a GPT model in Python using PyTorch. However, despite having a GPU, my code consistently evaluates to using the CPU.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import torch

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
```

Even after ensuring that my laptop's hybrid graphics mode is set to "Discrete" and rebooting the system, the code still detects and uses the CPU.

Are there any additional steps I should take to make Python recognize and utilize my laptop's GPU for CUDA operations?

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Additional Information:**

- Laptop Model: MSI Vector GP68HX 12VH
- GPU: NVIDIA GForce RTX 4080 laptop GPU
- Operating System: Win 11 Pro
- Python Version: 3.12.0
- PyTorch Version: 2.2.0+cpu

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong PyTorch version installed. I needed to uninstall PyTorch version 2.2.0+cpu and then used

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121`

for installation. Now, it successfully detects the CUDA cores.

Reference: [PyTorch - Get Started Locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)